# How do I convert Fri Mar 16 00:00:00 EDT 2007 into the format "yyyyMMdd" ? I'm using Talend but I can figure it out if I'm given Java code

Tags: java, date, talend

I'm given the date format: `Fri Mar 16 00:00:00 EDT 2007`

I thought the format was as follows: `ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'ICT' yyyy`, but no such luck.

In case anyone has used `Talend`, this is the code I tried:

```
!(Loan.OriginationDate == null) ?
TalendDate.isDate("Fri Mar 16 00:00:00 EDT 2007", "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'ICT' yyyy") ? "Correct Format" 

:":("
:null
```

Basically the code tests to see if the date is in the format `ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'ICT' yyyy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many hours of trail and error, I finally found it. The format is:

```
EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat` class of `java.txt` package

Have a look on related documentation here [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Talend's format was apparently slightly different. It's been solved but thanks for the input, that link is very helpful.